# How to show the second image of a product? PrestaShop 1.7.5.1

Tags: image, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I need to show a different cover image (the second, or the last, it's not important, all but not the first) only for a specific block: `ps_bestseller`.

The only thing I found is this code was this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40267160/how-to-display-in-product-list-the-cover-image-and-the-second-image-of-a-product), but it works only for the 1.6 version:

This is my default code:

```
{block name='product_thumbnail'}

    {if $product.cover}

      <a href="{$product.url}" class="thumbnail product-thumbnail">
        <img
          src = "{$product.cover.bySize.home_default.url}"
          alt = "{if !empty($product.cover.legend)}{$product.cover.legend}{else}{$product.name|truncate:30:'...'}{/if}"
          data-full-size-image-url = "{$product.cover.large.url}"
        >
      </a>
    {else}
      <a href="{$product.url}" class="thumbnail product-thumbnail">
        <img
          src = "{$urls.no_picture_image.bySize.home_default.url}"
        >
      </a>
    {/if}
  {/block}
```

When I try to edit the code it returns a blank page.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Create an override file that will be named `Link.php` in `override/classes/` with this content:

```
<?php
use PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Addon\Module\ModuleManagerBuilder;
use PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\SymfonyContainer;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Feature\TokenInUrls;

class Link extends LinkCore
{
    public function getLastImageLink($id_product, $product_name, $type = null) {
        $maxId = Db::getInstance()->getValue('SELECT id_image FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'image` WHERE id_product = '.(int)$id_product.'  ORDER BY position DESC');
        return $this->getImageLink($product_name, $id_product.'-'.$maxId, $type = null);
    }
}
```

Ensuite dans le tpl pour appeler l'url de votre image mettez :

```
{$link->getLastImageLink($product.id, $product.name, 'large')}
```

Regards

Comment: Thank you! I did but this part `{$link->getLastImageLink($product.id, $product.name, 'large')}` doesn't work. Blank page as result.
Maybe because I have the v. 1.7.5.1 ...
`{if $product.cover}
        
          <a href="{$product.url}" class="thumbnail product-thumbnail">
            <img
              src = "{$link->getLastImageLink($product.id, $product.name, 'large')}"
              alt = "{if !empty($product.cover.legend)}{$product.cover.legend}{else}{$product.name|truncate:30:'...'}{/if}"
              data-full-size-image-url = "{$product.cover.large.url}"`

Comment: Try delete the var / cache folder and activate error and with {$link->getLastImageLink($product.id_product, $product.name, 'large')}

Comment: Are you in debug mode ?

Comment: No, I made a mistake in the parameter of the function try with : {$link->getLastImageLink($product.id_product,'test', 'large')}